# Can anyone explain me why there's no WeakDelegate in .NET?

Tags: .net, weak-references, weak-events

I see no architectural constraints for implementing this entity.
.NET 4.5 does not have it, and WeakEventManager is still in the game.

I don't think guys in MS are lazy or stupid, so I suspect myself missing something very important. But what?...

Comment: A weak delegate would be a good idea IMO. Since it's the subscribers responsibility to decide if he wants a weak subscription. The publisher doesn't care.